# How to export visualized plot to png in Weka Explorer

Tags: plot, weka, data-visualization

I loaded a csv data to Weka Explorer, and click the visualize button, then I got the visualized plot, like this:

[image: Weka Explorer visualized plot]

Now I want to export this plot to a png file or other image format.
I did googled many times and searched many Weka tutorials, still no idea.
I'm totally a beginner to Weka, Any answer is appreciated :)

System: Mac OS X 10.10.5
Weka version: 3.7.12 oracle jvm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It is possible to generate image files from a number of `panels` in Weka's GUI interfaces. Just hold down shift and alt and left-click on the panel that you want to save. Available formats include: BMP, JPEG, PNG and postscript.**

It is also possible to save the visualization data out to an ARFF file - just use the "Save" button. You can then load it back into the Explorer and use any of Weka's filters to manipulate it.

[Source](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?76786-Visualizations-in-weka)

Comment: Btw, can I add axises label for the plot?

Comment: i think you can with an addon called Plot2D http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/~zimek/diplomathesis/implementations/EHNDs/doc/weka/gui/visualize/Plot2D.html

Comment: alt + **ctrl** + shift + left click worked for me. (on Linux)